# How can i find the index of the element of an Array?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, it gives me undefined i have also tried indexof() method

```
let Numbers = [2,3,1,5,6,7,8 ];`
console.log("Unsorted array " + Numbers);
for(var i=0 ;i<Numbers.length;i++){`
alert(Numbers.findIndex[i]);
}
```

Comment: The variable i _is_ the index.

Comment: Parens, not brackets: `findIndex(i)`, not `findIndex[i]`.

Comment: @NathanChampion He's looking for the index of the value of `i` in the array, not the value of the element at index i.

Comment: `findIndex` is a function that needs to be called with a callback function, not a number. `indexOf` expects to be passed a possible value of the array. As already said, `i` is already the index. If `i` is not what you are looking for then please provide more information about what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do here? Are you expecting each alert to be a value of the `Numbers` array or each index? For the former, use `alert(Numbers[i])`. For the latter, use `alert(i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code would work after some changes in your code -

```js
let Numbers = [2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8];
console.log("Unsorted array " + Numbers);
for (var i = 0; i < Numbers.length; i++) {
  console.log(Numbers.indexOf(Numbers[i]));
}
```

In your case, you were using `findIndex()` which takes a function and executes it for each element of the array. You were passing it a number which is not correct. Also, the invocation of function you were doing was not correct - use `()` brackets and not `[]` brackets for function call.

Also, the `i` itself is the index. I don't know why you would need to use `indexOf` to get the index of element which you already know is present at a particular index. This method wouldn't be practical unless your array has duplicates and you need to find the first occurring index number for each element of array.

As a side tip, avoid using alert for such purposes. Stick with console log.

Comment: Why are you posting it if it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @FelixKling Just to let the OP know the working code. Ofcourse it wouldnt be practical to use the code snipper I mentioned in answer but I just made clear about the errors OP had in his code

Comment: @Abhishek It works,you solved my problem..